# Existe algo parecido com prioridade de comandos em jquery?

Tags: jquery, keyframes, grid-layout

Eu estou criando uma página, e nessa página tem um menu lateral, e em cima da barra lateral tem um ícone de menu, que quando clicado faz a barra aparecer e desaparecer, pra desaparecer estou usando "display - none" e pra aparecer "display - grid", porquê estou usando "grid layout" para estilizar, o problema que eu estou tendo é na hora de criar as animações, quando é para o menu aparecer, a animação funciona, pra desaparecer, não, acho que é porque estou usando "display - none" e aí ele não faz a animação.

```
 $(function(){
  var sidebar_page = $('.sidebar-page')
  var content = $('.content')
  let footer = $('.footer')
  let tipoanimacao = 'testess teste'
  let tipoanimacao2 = 'testess teste2'


  $('.sidebar-toggle-box').on('click', function(){

    if (sidebar_page.css("display") == "none") {
      sidebar_page.css("display", "grid").addClass(tipoanimacao)
      content.css("grid-area", "2 / 2 / 3 / 3").addClass(tipoanimacao)
      footer.css("grid-area", "3 / 2 / 4 / 4").addClass(tipoanimacao)
    } else {
      sidebar_page.addClass(tipoanimacao2)
      content.removeClass(tipoanimacao).css("grid-area", "2 / 1 / 3 / 3")
      footer.removeClass(tipoanimacao).css("grid-area", "3 / 1 / 4 / 4")
      sidebar_page.css("display", "none")

    }

  });
});
```

eu gostaria de saber se tem como fazer ele primeiro executar a animação, e só depois da animação o display ficar 'none', eu já tentei com if, mas não  deu certo.

Outro problema que estou tendo também com animação, é o meu footer e o content, quando o display da barra lateral fica grid, eu estou mudando o começo da coluna de posição de 1 para 2 para fazer uma animação slide, e a barra lateral ficar na coluna 1

grid:

```
content.css("grid-area", "2 / 2 / 3 / 3").addClass(tipoanimacao)
footer.css("grid-area", "3 / 2 / 4 / 4").addClass(tipoanimacao)
```

none:

```
content.removeClass(tipoanimacao).css("grid-area", "2 / 1 / 3 / 3")
      footer.removeClass(tipoanimacao).css("grid-area", "3 / 1 / 4 / 4")
```

está funcionando, porém na hora de ele fazer a animação pra voltar pra coluna 2, o footer e o content ficam menores, porque ao invés de eles pegarem as 3 colunas da página inteira eles pegam só duas, e quando o efeito slide começa o lado direito da página fica em branco, então eu gostaria de saber se tem como a animação acontecer somente depois que o valor da coluna for mudada

esse é o trecho CSS de como eu dividi a página em 3 partes

```
.all-page-content {
    min-height: 100%;
    display: grid;
    grid-template-rows: 3em auto 3em;
    grid-template-columns: 10em auto 2em; }
```

e a animação que eu criei, eu não estou usando animate.css porque la não tem nenhuma igual eu quero

```
.testess {
  animation-name: teste;
  animation-duration: 0.8s;
  animation-fill-mode: both; }

@keyframes teste {
  0% {
    transform: translateX(-100px); }
  99% {
    transform: translateX(0px); } }
@keyframes teste2 {
  0% {
    transform: translateX(0px); }
  99% {
    transform: translateX(-155px); } }
```

HTML

```
<section class="all-page-content">

  <header>

    <div class="sidebar-toggle-box ">
      <i class="fas fa-bars"></i>
    </div>

    <div class="medium-column-header">

      <div class="search">
        <input type="search" name="search" value="" placeholder="Pesquisar"/>

        <button type="button" name="button"><i class="fas fa-search"></i></button>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="black-row"></div>

  </header>

  <aside class="sidebar-page">
    <nav>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#"> <div class=""><i class="fas fa-cogs"></i><p>loremsd</p></div></a>
          <ul>
            <li> <a href="#"> <div class="">dfdfd</div> </a></li>
            <li> <a href="#"> <div class="">dfdfd</div> </a></li>
            <li> <a href="#"> <div class="">dfdfd</div> </a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#"> <div class=""><i class="fab fa-btc"></i><p>lorisd</p></div> </a>
          <ul>
            <li> <a href="#"> <div class="">dfdfd</div> </a></li>
            <li> <a href="#"> <div class="">dfdfd</div> </a></li>
            <li> <a href="#"> <div class="">dfdfd</div> </a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#"> <div class=""><i class="fas fa-bell"></i><p>losari</p></div> </a></li>
        <li><a href="#"> <div class=""><i class="fas fa-chart-line"></i><p>loresa</p></div> </a></li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </aside>

  <aside class="right-sidebar">
    <address class="">
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#"><i class="fab fa-instagram"></i></a></li>
        <li><a href="#"><i class="fab fa-twitch"></i></a></li>
        <li><a href="#"><i class="fab fa-youtube"></i></a></li>
        <li><a href="#"><i class="fab fa-whatsapp"></i></a></li>
      </ul>
    </address>
  </aside>

  <section class="content">
    <article class="">
      <div class="tittle">
       <h6>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, est laborum.</h6>
      </div>

      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>

      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>

      <aside class="">
        <h6>Author: Giovani Lopes</h6>
        <data value="24/11/2022">24/11/1996</data>
      </aside>
    </article>

    <article class="">
      <div class="tittle">
        <h6>sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</h6>
      </div>

      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
    </article>
  </section>

  <footer class="footer">
    <div class="">
      <p>Copyright (c) 2018 Copyright Holder All Rights Reserved.</p>
    </div>
  </footer>

</section>
```

CSS Completo:

```
    * {
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
      text-decoration: none;
      list-style: none;
      box-sizing: border-box;
      color: black;
      outline: none; }

    html, body {
      height: 100%; }
      html .all-page-content, body .all-page-content {
        min-height: 100%;
        display: grid;
        grid-template-rows: 3em auto 3em;
        grid-template-columns: 10em auto 2em; }

    input[type="search"]::-webkit-search-decoration,
    input[type="search"]::-webkit-search-cancel-button,
    input[type="search"]::-webkit-search-results-button,
    input[type="search"]::-webkit-search-results-decoration {
      display: none; }

    input[type=search]::-ms-clear {
      display: none;
      width: 0;
      height: 0; }

    input[type=search]::-ms-reveal {
      display: none;
      width: 0;
      height: 0; }

header {
  grid-area: 1 / 1 / 2 / 4;
  background-color: #013243;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1.5em auto 1.5em;
  grid-template-rows: auto 0.1em;
  align-items: center; }
  header .black-row {
    grid-area: 2 / 1 / 3 / 4;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #012734;
    height: 0.1em; }
  header .sidebar-toggle-box {
    margin-left: 5px;
    grid-area: 1 / 1 / 2 / 2;
    cursor: pointer;
    border-radius: 2.4px;
    width: 1.8em;
    height: 1.6em;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center; }
    header .sidebar-toggle-box > i {
      color: #fff; }
  header .sidebar-toggle-box:hover {
    background: #012c3a; }
  header .medium-column-header {
    grid-area: 1 / 2 / 2 / 3;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: flex-end; }
    header .medium-column-header .search {
      display: flex;
      align-items: center;
      height: 1.8em;
      background-color: #012c3a;
      padding: 8px;
      border-radius: 5px; }
      header .medium-column-header .search ::-webkit-input-placeholder {
        color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5); }
      header .medium-column-header .search :-moz-placeholder {
        color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5); }
      header .medium-column-header .search ::-moz-placeholder {
        color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5); }
      header .medium-column-header .search :-ms-input-placeholder {
        color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5); }
      header .medium-column-header .search > input {
        background: none;
        border: none;
        width: 10em;
        height: 1.6em;
        color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.7); }
      header .medium-column-header .search > button {
        cursor: pointer;
        border: none;
        background: none; }
        header .medium-column-header .search > button i {
          font-size: 11px;
          color: #FDE3A7; }

.sidebar-page {
  grid-area: 2 / 1 / 4 / 2;
  width: 10em;
  background-color: #FDE3A7;
  padding: 10px 5px 0px 10px;
  overflow: visible;
  display: grid; }
  .sidebar-page > nav > ul > li > ul {
    display: none; }
  .sidebar-page nav > ul > li:hover > ul {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 1.8em auto;
    align-items: center; }
    .sidebar-page nav > ul > li:hover > ul > li {
      grid-column: 2/3; }
      .sidebar-page nav > ul > li:hover > ul > li:hover > a > div {
        background-color: #fcdb8e; }
      .sidebar-page nav > ul > li:hover > ul > li > a > div {
        padding: 0.25em;
        padding-left: 0.8em; }
  .sidebar-page nav > ul > li > a > div {
    height: 2.2em;
    padding: 5px;
    border-radius: 3px;
    align-items: center;
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 1.7em auto; }
    .sidebar-page nav > ul > li > a > div > i {
      grid-column: 1/2; }
    .sidebar-page nav > ul > li > a > div p {
      grid-column: 2/3; }
  .sidebar-page nav > ul > li > a > div:hover {
    background-color: #fcdb8e; }

.sidebar-page::after {
  content: '';
  height: 37.5em;
  background: #fcd375;
  width: 0.1em;
  display: block;
  margin-left: 9.2em;
  margin-top: -9.4em; }

.right-sidebar {
  grid-area: 2 / 3 / 3 / 4;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center; }

.content {
  -webkit-animation-duration: 3s;
  grid-area: 2 / 2 / 3 / 3;
  padding: 20px; }

.footer {
  grid-area: 3 / 2 / 4 / 4;
  transition: grid-area 50s linear;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  background-color: #013243; }

/*# sourceMappingURL=main.css.map */
```

Comment: Coloque o CSS completo para que possamos reproduzir a página.

Comment: pronto, ele está nessa formatação porque estou usando scss, não sei qual o melhor pra colocar aqui, então coloquei só o css mesmo